# Vaadin 23 change requestUrl from http to https

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Inside of the Vaadin generated html page I see the following line:

```
"contextRootUrl":"./","heartbeatInterval":300,"maxMessageSuspendTimeout":5000,"v-uiId":3,"requestURL":"http://examplecom/","productionMode":true,"appId":"ROOT-2521314","
```

I'm interested in the following part:

```
"requestURL":"http://example.com/"
```

Is it possible somehow to change the `requestUrl` from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`?

Answer (score 1):

That configuration is directly based on `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL`. If the page is requested over https, then the `requestURL` parameter will have https.

Comment: Thanks ! Is it possible to overwrite somehow? My app is hidden behind Nginx reverse proxy with SSL termination (NGINX on SSL, Vaadin app on HTTP). Maybe this is the reason of such behavior?

Comment: That sounds like a likely reason. One potential workaround would be to define a servlet filter that wraps the original request with an implementation that has a custom implementation of `getRequestURL`.